# Tycho cannot build client Product, problem with custom defined feature

Tags: eclipse, maven, build, eclipse-rcp, tycho

I use `Maven/Tycho` for building Eclipse RCP project and `p2-maven-plugin` for building the p2-site located on localhost. Calling `mvn clean install` on parent pom should build all modules and create client product zip, but some errors appear while building the product.

Error stacktrace

```
[INFO] --- target-platform-configuration:0.22.0:target-platform (default-target-platform) @ SplClientProduct ---
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.eclipse.tycho:target-platform-configuration:0.22.0:target-platform from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.eclipse.tycho:target-platform-configuration:0.22.0, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@425224ee]
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.eclipse.tycho:target-platform-configuration:0.22.0:target-platform' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) project = MavenProject: cz.tigra.spl:SplClientProduct:1.0.0 @ /tigra/SplClientProduct/pom.xml
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[DEBUG] Adding reactor project: MavenProject: cz.tigra.spl:cz.tigra.spl.client.feature:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT @ /tigra/cz.tigra.spl.client.feature/pom.xml
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- tycho-p2-publisher-plugin:0.22.0:publish-products (default-publish-products) @ SplClientProduct ---
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-p2-publisher-plugin:0.22.0:publish-products from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-p2-publisher-plugin:0.22.0, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@425224ee]
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-p2-publisher-plugin:0.22.0:publish-products' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) flavor = tooling
[DEBUG]   (f) project = MavenProject: cz.tigra.spl:SplClientProduct:1.0.0 @ /tigra/SplClientProduct/pom.xml
[DEBUG]   (f) qualifier = 
[DEBUG]   (f) session = org.apache.maven.execution.MavenSession@3a70dd47
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[DEBUG] No solution found because the problem is unsatisfiable.: [Unable to satisfy dependency from cz.tigra.spl.client.product 1.0.0 to cz.tigra.spl.client.feature.feature.group [1.0.0,1.0.1).; No solution found because the problem is unsatisfiable.]
[INFO] {osgi.ws=gtk, osgi.os=linux, osgi.arch=x86_64, org.eclipse.update.install.features=true}
[ERROR] Cannot resolve project dependencies:
[ERROR]   Software being installed: cz.tigra.spl.client.product 1.0.0
[ERROR]   Missing requirement: cz.tigra.spl.client.product 1.0.0 requires 'cz.tigra.spl.client.feature.feature.group [1.0.0,1.0.1)' but it could not be found
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] See http://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Dependency_Resolution_Troubleshooting for help.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] SplMavenRelease ................................... SUCCESS [4.117s]
[INFO] target-platform ................................... SUCCESS [0.106s]
[INFO] cz.tigra.spl.client.feature ....................... SUCCESS [0.629s]

....
success
....

[INFO] SplAggregator ..................................... SUCCESS [0.007s]
[INFO] SplClientProduct .................................. FAILURE [0.279s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1:50.453s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon May 24 11:36:53 UTC 2021
[INFO] Final Memory: 125M/1796M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-p2-publisher-plugin:0.22.0:publish-products (default-publish-products) on project SplClientProduct: Execution default-publish-products of goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-p2-publisher-plugin:0.22.0:publish-products failed: Cannot resolve dependencies of MavenProject: cz.tigra.spl:SplClientProduct:1.0.0 @ /tigra/SplClientProduct/pom.xml: See log for details -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-p2-publisher-plugin:0.22.0:publish-products (default-publish-products) on project SplClientProduct: Execution default-publish-products of goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-p2-publisher-plugin:0.22.0:publish-products failed: Cannot resolve dependencies of MavenProject: cz.tigra.spl:SplClientProduct:1.0.0 @ /tigra/SplClientProduct/pom.xml
```

Yes, I see the problem too - Product cannot see custom (in my project defined) feature called `cz.tigra.spl:cz.tigra.spl.client.feature`. My question is how to tell the Product where is my feature located/or where is path to its `feature.xml` (am I right?).

My p2-site

[image: p2 site root]

[image: feature directory]

Parent (main) `pom.xml` located in root folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>cz.tigra.spl</groupId>
    <artifactId>SplMavenRelease</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <eclipse-repo.url>http://download.eclipse.org/releases/latest</eclipse-repo.url>
        <tycho.version>0.22.0</tycho.version>
    </properties>

    <!--    p2 update or use target platform    -->
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>p2-site</id>
            <url>http://localhost:8080/site/</url>
            <layout>p2</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>

        <extensions>
            <extension>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
                <artifactId>wagon-ssh</artifactId>
                <version>2.10</version>
            </extension>
        </extensions>

        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tycho-p2-director-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${tycho.version}</version>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho.extras</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tycho-p2-extras-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${tycho.version}</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>

        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <meminitial>128m</meminitial>
                    <maxmem>1024m</maxmem>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>-XX:MaxPermSize=256m</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${tycho.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>tycho-packaging-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${tycho.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <id>package-feature</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <finalName>${project.artifactId}_${unqualifiedVersion}.${buildQualifier}</finalName>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
                <version>${tycho.version}</version>

                <configuration>

                    <dependency-resolution>
                        <extraRequirements>
                            <requirement>
                                <type>eclipse-plugin</type>
                                <id>org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64</id>
                                <versionRange>[0.0.0,5.0.0)</versionRange>
                            </requirement>
                            <requirement>
                                <type>eclipse-plugin</type>
                                <id>org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64</id>
                                <versionRange>[0.0.0,5.0.0)</versionRange>
                            </requirement>
                        </extraRequirements>
                    </dependency-resolution>

<!--                    <pomDependencies>consider</pomDependencies>-->
                    <filters>
                        <!-- work around Equinox bug 348045 -->
                        <filter>
                            <type>p2-installable-unit</type>
                            <id>org.eclipse.equinox.servletbridge.extensionbundle</id>
                            <removeAll/>
                        </filter>
                    </filters>

                    <executionEnvironment>JavaSE-1.6</executionEnvironment>
                    <!-- more settings -->
                    <environments>
                        <environment>
                            <os>linux</os>
                            <ws>gtk</ws>
                            <arch>x86_64</arch>
                        </environment>
                        <environment>
                            <os>win32</os>
                            <ws>win32</ws>
                            <arch>x86_64</arch>
                        </environment>
                        <!--                        <environment>-->
                        <!--                            <os>macosx</os>-->
                        <!--                            <ws>cocoa</ws>-->
                        <!--                            <arch>x86_64</arch>-->
                        <!--                        </environment>-->
                    </environments>

                    <target>
                        <artifact>
                            <groupId>cz.tigra.spl</groupId>
                            <artifactId>target-platform</artifactId>
                            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                        </artifact>
                    </target>

                </configuration>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>tycho-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${tycho.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>plugin-source</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>plugin-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.xtend</groupId>
                <artifactId>xtend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>xtend-gen</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt</groupId>
                        <artifactId>org.eclipse.jdt.core</artifactId>
                        <version>3.12.2</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.eclipse.platform</groupId>
                        <artifactId>org.eclipse.core.runtime</artifactId>
                        <version>3.12.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.eclipse.platform</groupId>
                        <artifactId>org.eclipse.equinox.common</artifactId>
                        <version>3.8.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.ibm.icu</groupId>
                        <artifactId>icu4j</artifactId>
                        <version>52.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <modules>
        <module>target-platform</module>
        <module>cz.tigra.spl.client.feature</module>
        <module>SplAggregator</module>
        <module>SplClientProduct</module>
<!--        <module>p2-site</module>-->
    </modules>

</project>
```

SplAggregator just aggregates all project modules with source code.

Target platform pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>cz.tigra.spl</groupId>
        <artifactId>SplMavenRelease</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>cz.tigra.spl</groupId>
    <artifactId>target-platform</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>eclipse-target-definition</packaging>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.22.0</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

and `target-platform.target` file

```
<?pde version="3.6"?>
<target name="target-platform" sequenceNumber="10">
    <locations>
        <location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeConfigurePhase="true" includeMode="planner" includeSource="true"
                  type="InstallableUnit">
<!--    this doesn't work, that's why it's commented -->
<!--            <unit id="cz.tigra.spl.client.feature" version="1.0.0.202105240921"/>-->
<!--            <repository location="localhost:8080/site/features/"/>-->
        </location>
    </locations>
    <targetJRE
            path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.6"/>
    <launcherArgs>
        <vmArgs>-Xmx1024m</vmArgs>
        <programArgs>-consoleLog</programArgs>
    </launcherArgs>
</target>
```

feature's `pom.xml` and `feature.xml` files:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

        <parent>
            <groupId>cz.tigra.spl</groupId>
            <artifactId>SplMavenRelease</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </parent>

    <groupId>cz.tigra.spl</groupId>
    <artifactId>cz.tigra.spl.client.feature</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>eclipse-feature</packaging>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.22.0</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    
</project>
```

[image: feature.xml]

Product's `pom.xml` and `SplClient.product`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>SplMavenRelease</artifactId>
        <groupId>cz.tigra.spl</groupId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>cz.tigra.spl</groupId>
    <artifactId>SplClientProduct</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>eclipse-repository</packaging>
    <name>SplClientProduct</name>

    <properties>
        <product.finalName>SPL</product.finalName>
        <product.id>cz.tigra.spl.client.product</product.id>
        <product.outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/products/${product.id}/win32/win32/x86_64</product.outputDirectory>
    </properties>

    <repositories>

    <repository>
        <id>p2-site</id>
        <url>http://localhost:8080/site/</url>
        <layout>p2</layout>
    </repository>

    </repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>tycho-p2-director-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>materialize-products</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>materialize-products</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                <execution>
                    <!-- create zip file with the installed product -->
                    <id>archive-products</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>archive-products</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?pde version="3.5"?>

<product name="SPL" uid="cz.tigra.spl.client.product" id="cz.tigra.spl.client.product" application="cz.tigra.spl.client.application" version="1.0.0" useFeatures="true" includeLaunchers="true">

   <aboutInfo>
      <image path="/cz.tigra.spl.client/images/about/about.png"/>
      <text>
         text pro about se bere z messages.properties (lokalizovany)
      </text>
   </aboutInfo>

   <configIni use="default">
      <win32>/config.ini</win32>
   </configIni>

   <launcherArgs>
      <programArgs>-data
@user.home/SPL@deployment.mode/workspace
-configuration
@user.home/SPL@deployment.mode/configuration
-clean</programArgs>
      <vmArgs>-Xms256M 
-Xmx1024M
-XX:PermSize=64M 
-XX:MaxPermSize=128M</vmArgs>
      <vmArgsMac>-XstartOnFirstThread -Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts</vmArgsMac>
   </launcherArgs>

   <windowImages i16="/cz.tigra.spl.client/icons/16_16/spl.png" i32="/cz.tigra.spl.client/icons/32_32/spl.png"/>

   <splash
      location="cz.tigra.spl.client"
      startupProgressRect="5,275,445,15" />
   <launcher name="spl">
      <solaris/>
      <win useIco="true">
         <ico path="/cz.tigra.spl.client/images/logo/logo.ico"/>
         <bmp/>
      </win>
   </launcher>

   <vm>
   </vm>

   <plugins>
   </plugins>

   <features>
      <feature id="cz.tigra.spl.client.feature" version="1.0.0.qualifier"/>
   </features>

   <configurations>
      <plugin id="cz.tigra.spl.client" autoStart="true" startLevel="0" />
    ...
custom plugins definition
    ...
      <plugin id="cz.tigra.spl.core" autoStart="true" startLevel="2" />
      <plugin id="org.springframework.osgi.extender" autoStart="true" startLevel="1" />
   </configurations>

</product>
```

So I guess it isn't enought to have `cz.tigra.spl.client.feature` located on p2 site, because Product cannot see it - where it should be? Or what is need to be changed in project setup?

Thanks!

Comment: There are a many weird things: [`<tycho.version>0.22.0</tycho.version>` is more than 6 years behind](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Release_Notes); `<eclipse-repo.url>http://download.eclipse.org/releases/latest</eclipse-repo.url>` is up to date but it seems not be used; in the parent POM there is a p2 repository (which is not recommended) and a target platform definition file with a commented out install unit where in the ID the `.feature.group` suffix is missing (for a feature that is not required here since it's build in parent POM), `http://localhost:8080/...` instead of `file://...`, etc.

Comment: I would recommend to start with https://github.com/vogellacompany/tycho-example and then adapt it step by step to your needs. But that's just a suggestion and not a reason for attacking people who want to help you again.